# Sequential Running of Scripts in SQL Server (without using a batch file)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 30 scripts of SQL code that I have been told to execute one by one (in a certain order) within SQL Server.
I am unable to use a batch file to do so (for reasons out of my control) and from another Question/Answer on this site I believe I can do something like the following:

In the SQL Management Studio open a new query and type all files as below

```
:r c:\Scripts\script1.sql
:r c:\Scripts\script2.sql
:r c:\Scripts\script3.sql
```

Go to Query menu on SQL Management Studio and make sure SQLCMD Mode is enabled
Click on SQLCMD Mode; files will be selected in grey as below

```
:r c:\Scripts\script1.sql

:r c:\Scripts\script2.sql

:r c:\Scripts\script3.sql
```

Now execute

My problem is my files have whitespace in their names for example:
'7. Address and Phone Number.sql'

I have been toying around with it trying to get the above method to work to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just double-click the file and open it in SSMS, then click Execute manually? It's slightly more tedious, but not by much.

Comment: @jw11432, OP mentions *30* SQL scripts. So likely, needs an automated solution.

Comment: I noticed the number. But as no mention was made as to how long each query, or all queries combined would take to run, nor if this is going to be a one-off event, I just wonder if more time may be spent looking for a solution rather than just running them manually lol

Comment: @hw11432 Each query takes between 30 seconds and 40 minutes, total of about 2 hours and they have to all be run once every day or two. I'm just looking for a solution so I don't have to sit around and open a new script and hit execute 30 times

Answer (score 0):

Consider most *any* programming language (Java, C#, C++, Python, PHP, VB) to iterate through scripts in file directory and call [`sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-start-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) at command line. Recall `sqlcmd` is a separate executable tool with MSSQL installations, allowing command line interfacing to SQL Server (apart from IDEs like SSMS) and is available in both Windows and Linux installations.

Specifically, follow how to [Run Transact-SQL Script Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files?view=sql-server-ver15). For batch jobs, use command line interpreters like Window's PowerShell and Unix's Bash.

**PowerShell** *(save as .ps1 and run in PS ISE or PS terminal)*

```bsh
Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts" -Filter *.sql | 
Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "sqlcmd" -S myServer\instanceName -i $_.FullName
    # Invoke-Expression "& sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i $_.FullName"
}
```

**Bash** *(save as .sh and run in IDE or terminal)*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in C:/Scripts/*.sql; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    ./sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i "$file"
done
```